# I have an issue with z type array declaration in this program

Tags: java, arrays

Can any one please explain me that how the output of this program is 14 and why we have declared array as int[]...z in function go parameter list.

```
public class Venus 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      int [] x = {1,2,3};
      int y[] = {4,5,6};
      new Venus().go(x,y);
    }

    void go(int[]... z) 
    {
        for(int[] a : z)
          System.out.print(a[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you know what your code is doing?

Comment: Suggest you try going through it with a debugger, it will help you understand.

Comment: It seems to me it's some kind of exercise. Nobody would write a code like this... It's a good overview of the array syntax in Java, you should maybe try to understand it by yourself.

Comment: This question has tricky varargs syntax. I think that's where confusion is.

Answer (score 3):

The `int[]...` notation is the [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) notation.

It means that your `go(int[]... z)` method accepts several `int[]` as arguments. Inside the method, `z` int of type `int[][]`.

Therefore, what `go` does is that for each int-array `a` in `z`, it prints the first element of `a`. That's why `1` (`x[0]`) and then `4` (`y[0]`) are printed => `14`

Answer (score 0):

First the method go takes an Array of int Arrays:

```
void go(int[]... z)
```

Second, you passed x and y arrays.

```
new Venus().go(x,y);
```

then asked to print the first element from each Array

```
for(int[] a : z) // a is a temp veriable hold one element from the passed array of array and z represents the array of int arrays which is {x, y}
      System.out.print(a[0]);
```

So the Output is 14

Answer (score 0):

The method `go` accepts a variable length sequence of int arrays, iterates through the arguments, and prints the first element of each one. When you pass x and y, it prints the first element of x (which is 1) and the first element of y (which is 4), so 14.

Answer (score 0):

As your example

```
  int [] x = {1,2,3};
  int y[] = {4,5,6};
  new Venus().go(x,y);
```

when it calls **go(int[]... z)** actually it does

```
 int[][] z = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Since its array size is two. So loop will turn 2 times

**loop 1:**

```
int[]a = z[0]; // z[0] is {1,2,3}  
System.out.print(a[0]); // a[0] is 1
```

**loop 2:**

```
int[]a = z[1];  //z[1] is {4,5,6}
System.out.print(a[0]); // a[0] is 4
```